# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object frequently

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting this error very frequently but not everytime.

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I am using following code:

```
Category n = new Category { 
                     ID = id, 
                     name = TxtName.Text, 
                     TopNav = Convert.ToInt32(Chk_Top.SelectedItem.Value), 
                     LeftNav = Convert.ToByte(Chk_Left.Checked ? "1" : "0"), 
                     Active = Convert.ToByte(Chk_Active.Checked ? "1" : "0"), 
                     Rank = Convert.ToInt32(Txt_position.Text), 
                     ParentID = pid, 
                     Image = name, 
                     Content = Content.Text, 
                     PageTitle = Txt_SpeakerTitle.Text, 
                     PageName = Txt_SpeakerTitle.Text, 
                     speakerpreview = Txt_Previewdesc.Text, 
                     PageDesc = Txt_SpeakerTitle.Text, 
                     PageKeyword = Txt_SpeakerTitle.Text, 
                     Filehandler = "speaker", 
                     SpeakerDetail = speakerdesc.Text, 
                     SpeakerTitle = Txt_SpeakerTitle.Text, 
                     SpotLightdesc = spotlightcontent.Text, 
                     Chk_Spot = Convert.ToByte(Chk_Spot.Checked ? "1" : "0"),
                     Catalogue = Catalogue };

db.Categories.InsertOnSubmit(n);
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is something null in your code. debug and watch your properties and objects until you found the one which is null.

Comment: Which line are you getting it on? It means that frequently one of those values you are setting is null, and so you are failing. There is now way for us to tell you which one it is.

Comment: For debugging purposes, remove the concise object initialization, i.e. set every property separately. You can then see the line on which it breaks.

Comment: 'Chk_Top.SelectedItem.Value' may be the culprit but as bittech has suggested, debugger should help in analyzing the error.

Comment: Very frequently Chk_Top.SelectedItem is null but not everytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the line and hover over each property.

Another approach could be to use Code Contracts, like so:

```
Contract.Assert(TxtName != null);
Contract.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtName.Text));
Contract.Assert(Chk_Top != null);
Contract.Assert(Chk_Top.SelectedItem != null);
... etc.
```

before the code you show above. This verifies your assumptions and throws an exception when an assumption is not met.

This has the advantage that all of these values are checked in the DEBUG version of your code every time you run, but the checks are left out of the RELEASE compilation.

This way you can pinpoint the problem and search further, figuring out what goes wrong.